# I cannot enter the Wordpress login page (404)

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, http-status-code-404, wp-admin

on my website [www.dubaitaxation.ae](http://www.dubaitaxation.ae) i cannot access the WordPress login page which is [www.dubaitaxation.ae/wp-admin](http://www.dubaitaxation.ae/wp-admin) or wp-login. It redirects to /wordpress/wp-admin and shows an Error 404 Not Found. Can anyone please get me out of this?

PS. I am a beginner and the website is hosted on AWS EC2

Comment: seems like your site url or home url is wrong in your database

Comment: all your links (stylesheets, themefiles etc) is being loaded at http://ec2-13-127-23-81.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/(filename) - so i guess that something is wrong with your site-url

Comment: Your site url has a `/wordpress/` sufix. remove this and use only the domain, or move your wordpress file to the folder.

Comment: @Maxwells.c how do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked your page source and it shows http://ec2-13-127-23-81.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com/wordpress  as the  ABSPATH.

This means in your settings ( *_options  table )  one or both of these is set to `http://ec2-13-127-23-81.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com/wordpress`  instead of  `www.dubaitaxation.ae`   :  `siteurl`   or  `home`

You can try to update this using this function ***if you cannot do this in the database directly***.

```
function updateUrl(){

    update_option("siteurl","www.dubaitaxation.ae");
    update_option("home","www.dubaitaxation.ae");

}add_action("after_setup_theme", "updateUrl")
```

Put this in your **active theme** 's functions.php file and go to the home page.

It should reset the options and once that is done, **remember to remove the function from functions.php**

Comment: I didn't understand the last line which is removing the function from functions.php

Comment: Ok. I think the problem is solved. I added "define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');" these two lines with my domain url in the wp_config.php file and it works now

Comment: Thanks a lot! Have a nice day!

Comment: the problem of this method is that it will not be stored on the database. Also, another answer has told you to do this, not this one...

Comment: But when i make any changes in functions.php then the site shows error 500

Answer (score 1):

When i tried your login URL it gets redirected to some other URL.Please check with it. Your SITE_URL and HOME_URL not configured properly. CSS files missing. Please check with that.

Once i have replaced with your domain URL its working.Please find it below

http://www.dubaitaxation.ae/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dubaitaxation.ae%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

Comment: Yes, but after I enter login details, it displays the same error